# Game lagging (beginner)

Tags: c#, xna, lag

I am creating a game in which asteroids spawn and move down the screen. In the update method of the game, i am using a random number to spawn the asteroids sporatically. When i start it up, it begins to lag within the first 5 seconds. I can see this because the score counter(which goes up every tick) starts going in intervals of 30. Also, the images of the asteroid do not even show up.

Here is the gameObject class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;  
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net;  
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;


namespace thedodger
{
public abstract class gameObject
{
    public static Texture2D texture;
    public Rectangle rectangle;

    public abstract void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch);
    public abstract void Update(GameTime gameTime);
}
}
```

here is the asteroid class;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;

namespace thedodger
{
public class Asteroid : gameObject
{
    Random rand = new Random(1);
    int yPos = -10;

    public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(rand.Next(32,400),      yPos,32,32),Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        yPos--;


    }
}
}
```

and here is the game1 class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;

namespace thedodger
{
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    int scorevalue = 0;
    SpriteFont font;
    player player1 = new player();
    List<gameObject> objectList = new List<gameObject>();
    Random rand = new Random(1);
    Asteroid asteroid = new Asteroid();


    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("font");
        //player1.image = Content.Load<Texture2D>("EnemyShip005.png");
        gameObject.texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("asteroid");

        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        scorevalue++;

        if (rand.Next(0, 8) == 2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {

                objectList.Add(asteroid);


            }
        }

        foreach (Asteroid asteroid in objectList)
        {
            asteroid.Update(gameTime);
            asteroid.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }



        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        // TODO: Add your update logic here

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
         spriteBatch.Begin();
         spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Score: " + scorevalue, new Vector2(5, 5), Color.White);
         spriteBatch.End();



        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
}
```

All help would be greatly appreciated.
sorry about the code. I am having difficult setting it up. Help on that too please.

Comment: This looks like a question for the [game development site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). There are probably much more XNA specialists than here. And the first bug I spotted: you have always exactly one `Asteroid` object which is updated _and_ drawn multiples of 30 times each frame.

Answer (score 4):

As Tobias said, you probably should have put this on the Game Dev site and you appear to only have one `Asteroid` instantiated. In the Game1 object, you declare and instantiate an `Asteroid` object. Then in the Update method you add it repeatedly to the `objectList`. To get what I think you want, you should change

```
Asteroid asteroid = new Asteroid();
```

to

```
Asteroid asteroid;
```

Then change

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    objectList.Add(asteroid);
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    asteroid = new Asteroid();
    objectList.Add(asteroid);
}
```

In your original code you declare and instantiate `asteroid` as a specific `Asteroid` but then never change it. So, throughout the whole program `asteroid` is pointed to one specific instance of an `Asteroid`. Then you repeatedly add `asteroid` to the objectList. So after each frame, 30 new references to the same `asteroid` object are being added to the `objectList` and the `Update()` and `Draw()` methods are being called on `asteroid` for every reference to it in `objectList`. So after 30 frames, one second if running at 30FPS, up to 900 references to the same exact `asteroid` object are in `objectList` and on that 30th frame `asteroid` is having its `Update()` and `Draw()` methods called up to 900 times. I'm pretty sure this is the source of your lag. Doing the corrections given above will result in `objectList` being populated with up to 900 *different* `Asteroid`s, but will certainly experience lag as well. What you need to do as well is add a limit to the amount of asteroids on screen at any given time (the length of `objectList` can only be x amount) and/or lower the amount of asteroids created each time. I would suggest something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (objectList.Count < 50) // Maximum asteroids on screen
    {
        asteroid = new Asteroid();
        objectList.Add(asteroid);
    }
}
```

will result in only five new asteroids for time and a maximum of 50 at any given time. If you add in functionality to destroy asteroids though, you'll have to remember to remove them from the `objectList`.

EDIT- As Neomex has said, your drawing is also a problem. I would suggest checking out the GDC 2008 talk on the XNA Framework performance here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6082
It very briefly covers some drawing and calculation performances and what you should/shouldn't do.

EDIT2- Actually, because of your random probability, it would be up to 900 object references and calls, not a full 900.

Answer (score 3):

Try to make as least begin-end calls as possible, they often slow down game a lot.
( Asteroid class )

You are displaying graphics in your update function which is really bad thing.

If these fail, try to download newest drivers.

Reasuming:

Change in your asteroid class

```
public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(rand.Next(32,400),      yPos,32,32),Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();

}
```

to

```
public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(rand.Next(32,400),      yPos,32,32),Color.White);
}
```

Now in your update function

```
foreach (Asteroid asteroid in objectList)
{
    asteroid.Update(gameTime);
    asteroid.Draw(spriteBatch);
}
```

to

```
foreach (Asteroid asteroid in objectList)
{
    asteroid.Update(gameTime);
}
```

And add this in draw function:

```
foreach (Asteroid asteroid in objectList)
{
    asteroid.Draw(spriteBatch);
}
```

Comment: Something to add to what @Neomex has said, your draw and update calls may not necessarily be in a 1:1 relationship. That's why you should separate your draws from your updates.

Answer (score 0):

As Tobias has already pointed out, you are using the same asteriod object every time you want to spawn a new asteriod. You need to do add a `new Asteriod()` to the object list instead of using the same one.

Also, this code is mostly likely the reason you are suffering performance wise.

```
    if (rand.Next(0, 8) == 2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {

            objectList.Add(asteroid);


        }
    }
```

You are adding 30 instances of the same object to the collection on every update call (with is around 60 times a second). I realize you are using a random number, but it sill happens to about 12.5% of the update calls.

So within a 5-10 seconds, you now have thousands of these objects and are drawing the same image thousands and thousands of times.

Comment: Thanks you guys. This will help alot.